# How to load nested collections in hive with more than 3 levels

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I'm struggling to load data into Hive, defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE complexstructure (
id STRING,
date DATE,
day_data ARRAY<STRUCT<offset:INT,data:MAP<STRING,FLOAT>>>
) row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '|'
map keys terminated by ':';
```

The day_data field contains a complex structure difficult to load with `load data inpath...`
I've tried with `'\004'`, `^D`... a lot of options, but the data inside the map doesn't get loaded.

Here is my last try:

```
id_3054,2012-09-  22,3600000:TOT'\005'0.716'\004'PI'\005'0.093'\004'PII'\005'0.0'\004'PIII'\005'0.0'\004'PIV'\005'0.0'\004'RES'\005'0.0|7200000:TOT'\005'0.367'\004'PI'\005'0.066'\004'PII'\005'0.0'\004'PIII'\005'0.0'\004'PIV'\005'0.0'\004'RES'\005'0.0|10800000:TOT'\005'0.268'\004'PI'\005'0.02'\004'PII'\005'0.0'\004'PIII'\005'0.0'\004'PIV'\005'0.159'\004'RES'\005'0.0|14400000:TOT'\005'0.417'\004'PI'\005'0.002'\004'PII'\005'0.0'\004'PIII'\005'0.0'\004'PIV'\005'0.165'\004'RES'\005'0.0`
```

Before posting here, I've tried (many many) options, and this example doesn't work:

[HIVE nested ARRAY in MAP data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812025/hive-nested-array-in-map-data-type)

I'm using the image from HDP 2.2

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found a nice way to generate the file from java. The trick is that Hive uses the first 8 ASCII characters as separators, but you can only override the first three. From the fourth on, you need to generate thee actual ASCII charaters.

After many tests, I ended up editing my file with an HEX editor, and inserting the right value worked, but how can I do that in Java? Can't be more simple: just cast an int into char, and that will generate the corresponding ASCII character:

```
ASCII 4 -> ((char)4)
ASCII 5 -> ((char)5)
...
```

And so on.

Hope this helps!!

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

You could store Hive table in Parquet or ORC format which support nested structures natively and more efficiently.