# Apache Hive - Complex DataType Map<string, struct> not working

Tags: hive

Hive Version **2.1.1**

**Problem Description:** collection items terminated values are inserted as Map Keys

**Hive Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE profiles(
id int,
name struct<first_name: string, middle_name: string, last_name: string>,
phone struct<home: string, office: string>,
address map<string,struct<streat:string, appartment:int, zip:string>>
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '-'
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '='
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

**Data:**

```
1000,Suresh--S,1234567890-1234567890,home=Venkatapuram1-2020-500001
1001,Mahesh-X-M,1234567890-1234567890,home=Venkatapuram2-2021-500001
```

**Data Load:**

```
load data inpath '/handson/profiles_data.txt' overwrite into table profiles;
```

**Actual data from select statement:**

```
SELECT * FROM profiles; 

1000        
{"first_name":"Suresh","middle_name":"","last_name":"S"}        
{"home":"1234567890","office":"1234567890"}     
{"home": 
{"streat":"Venkatapuram1",**"appartment":null,"zip":null},"2020":null, 
"500001": null}

1001        
{"first_name":"Mahesh","middle_name":"X","last_name":"M"}        
{"home":"1234567890","office":"1234567890"}
{"home": 
{"streat":"Venkatapuram2",**"appartment":null,"zip":null},"2021":null, 
"500001": null}
```

**Expected:**

```
1000        
{"first_name":"Suresh","middle_name":"","last_name":"S"}        
{"home":"1234567890","office":"1234567890"}
{"home":{"streat":"Venkatapuram1",**"appartment":2020,"zip":"500001"}**}

1001        
{"first_name":"Mahesh","middle_name":"X","last_name":"M"}        
{"home":"1234567890","office":"1234567890"} 
{"home": {"streat":"Venkatapuram2",**"appartment":2021,"zip":"500001"**}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in: [HIVE nested ARRAY in MAP data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812025/hive-nested-array-in-map-data-type), you can only override the first three delimiters in hive, while hive actually supports 8. In nested data structures, for each nesting level, a consequent delimiter is used.

In your hive table, the delimiter between fields in the struct that is inside the `address` map is \u004 (Unicode 4), and it can't be overridden.

You should change your input to:

```
1000,Suresh--S,1234567890-1234567890,home=Venkatapuram1\u00042020\u0004500001 
1001,Mahesh-X-M,1234567890-1234567890,home=Venkatapuram2\u00042021\u0004500001
```

Comment: not working
hive> select * from test_stg;
OK
1       JOHN    ["abu1","abu2"] {"key1":[null],"key2":[null]}
Time taken: 0.126 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Comment: Still not working:
hive> select * from profiles;
OK
1000    {"first_name":"Suresh","middle_name":"","last_name":"S"}        {"home":"1234567890","office":"1234567890"}     {"home":{"streat":"Venkatapuram1\\u00042020\\u0004500001 ","appartment":null,"zip":null}}
1001    {"first_name":"Mahesh","middle_name":"X","last_name":"M"}       {"home":"1234567890","office":"1234567890"}     {"home":{"streat":"Venkatapuram2\\u00042021\\u0004500001","appartment":null,"zip":null}}
Time taken: 0.083 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive>

Comment: It seems that you added \u0004 as text. You should insert the actual Unicode character

Comment: Appreciated, working awesome :)
hive> select * from profiles;
OK
1000    {"first_name":"Suresh","middle_name":"","last_name":"S"}        {"home":"1234567890","office":"1234567890"}     {"home":{"streat":"Venkatapuram1","appartment":2020,"zip":"500001 "}}
1001    {"first_name":"Mahesh","middle_name":"X","last_name":"M"}       {"home":"1234567890","office":"1234567890"}     {"home":{"streat":"Venkatapuram2","appartment":2021,"zip":"500001"}}
Time taken: 0.051 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive>